I'm having issue invalidating queries after mutation
Body:
I'm working on a React project that involves handling money transfer operations using React Query for data fetching and state management. I'm encountering an issue where the query does not invalidate after a successful transaction unless I manually invalidate it using the React Query DevTools or leave Chrome and come back, which then triggers the invalidation (update).
Here is my code for the transfer functionality and the hooks:
Transfer.js file:
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import supabase from "../supabase";
import { useState } from "react";

const transferMoneyApi = async (tranferInfo) => {
  const { accountId, amount } = tranferInfo;
  const FormattedAmount = Number(amount);
  console.log(FormattedAmount);
  const description = "";
  
  const { data: senderAccount, error: senderError } = await supabase
    .from("accounts")
    .select("*")
    .eq("accountId", accountId);

  console.log(senderAccount, senderError);

  if (senderError) {
    throw new Error(senderError.message || "Errors fetching sender account data");
  }

  const senderBalance = senderAccount.map((acc) => acc.accountBalance).at(0);

  if (senderBalance < FormattedAmount) {
    throw new Error("Insufficient balance to transfer");
  }

  const UpdatedSenderBalance = senderBalance - FormattedAmount;
  console.log(UpdatedSenderBalance);

  await supabase
    .from("accounts")
    .update({ accountBalance: UpdatedSenderBalance })
    .eq("accountId", accountId);

  await supabase.from("transactions").insert([
    {
      accountId: String(accountId),
      amount: -amount,
      type: "debit",
      description,
      status: "successful",
      name: "Lawal",
    },
  ]);

  return { message: "Money Transfer successful" };
};

export const useTransferMoney = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [transactionSuccess, setTransactionSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [insufficientBalance, setInsufficientBalance] = useState(false);

  const {
    mutate: transferMoney,
    isPending: isTransferring,
    error: transferError,
  } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: transferMoneyApi,
    onSuccess: async () => {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["account"] });
      setTransactionSuccess(true);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.message === "Insufficient balance to transfer") {
        setInsufficientBalance(true);
      }
    },
  });

  return {
    transferMoney,
    transactionSuccess,
    setTransactionSuccess,
    insufficientBalance,
    setInsufficientBalance,
    isTransferring,
    transferError,
  };
};

Data fetching hooks:
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import supabase from "../supabase";
import { accountIdInfo, customerIdInfo } from "../utility/utilityFunction";

const accountIdInfoData = accountIdInfo();
const customerIdInfoData = customerIdInfo();

const fetchCustomerData = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("customers")
    .select("*")
    .eq("customerId", customerIdInfoData);
  if (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
  return data;
};

const fetchAccountData = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("accounts")
    .select("*")
    .eq("accountId", accountIdInfoData);
  if (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
  return data;
};

const fetchTransactions = async (accountData) => {
  const accountId = accountData?.map((acc) => acc.accountId).at(0);
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("transactions")
    .select("*")
    .eq("accountId", accountId);

  if (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
  return data;
};

export const useCustomerData = () => {
  const {
    isPending: isLoadingCustomerData,
    data: customerData,
    error: errorCustomerData,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["customer"],
    queryFn: fetchCustomerData,
  });
  console.log("Customer Data:", customerData);

  return { isLoadingCustomerData, customerData, errorCustomerData };
};

export const useAccountData = () => {
  const {
    isPending: isLoadingAccountData,
    data: accountData,
    error: errorAccountData,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["account"],
    queryFn: fetchAccountData,
  });
  return { isLoadingAccountData, accountData, errorAccountData };
};

export const useTransactions = (accountData) => {
  const {
    isPending: isLoadingTransactions,
    data: transactionsData,
    error: errorTransactions,
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["transactions"],
    queryFn: () => fetchTransactions(accountData),
  });

  return { isLoadingTransactions, transactionsData, errorTransactions };
};

Issue: After a successful transaction, the query does not invalidate as expected. The data only updates if I manually invalidate the query using the React Query DevTools or if I leave Chrome and come back.

A potential fix might be to check the "invalidateQueries" call
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import supabase from "../supabase";
import { useState } from "react";

const transferMoneyApi = async (tranferInfo) => {
   const { accountId, amount } = tranferInfo;
   const FormattedAmount = Number(amount);
   console.log(FormattedAmount);
   const description = "";

   const { data: senderAccount, error: senderError } = await supabase
    .from("accounts")
    .select("*")
    .eq("accountId", accountId);

   console.log(senderAccount, senderError);

   if (senderError) {
     throw new Error(senderError.message || "Errors fetching sender 
     account data");
   }

   const senderBalance = senderAccount.map((acc) => 
   acc.accountBalance).at(0);

   if (senderBalance < FormattedAmount) {
     throw new Error("Insufficient balance to transfer");
   }

   const UpdatedSenderBalance = senderBalance - FormattedAmount;
   console.log(UpdatedSenderBalance);

   await supabase
     .from("accounts")
     .update({ accountBalance: UpdatedSenderBalance })
     .eq("accountId", accountId);

  await supabase.from("transactions").insert([
    {
     accountId: String(accountId),
     amount: -amount,
     type: "debit",
     description,
     status: "successful",
     name: "Lawal",
   },
 ]);

 return { message: "Money Transfer successful" };
 };

export const useTransferMoney = () => {
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const [transactionSuccess, setTransactionSuccess] = useState(false);
const [insufficientBalance, setInsufficientBalance] = useState(false);
const {
  mutate: transferMoney,
  isPending: isTransferring,
  error: transferError,
} = useMutation({
  mutationFn: transferMoneyApi,
  onSuccess: async () => {
    await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["account"] });
    console.log('Query invalidated');
    setTransactionSuccess(true);
  },
  onError: (error) => {
  console.log(error);
  if (error.message === "Insufficient balance to transfer") {
    setInsufficientBalance(true);
  }
 },
});

return {
  transferMoney,
  transactionSuccess,
  setTransactionSuccess,
  insufficientBalance,
  setInsufficientBalance,
  isTransferring,
  transferError,
 };
};

Then you can also now force re-fetch after the invalidation to make sure it updates instantly
onSuccess: async () => {
  await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["account"] });
  await queryClient.refetchQueries({ queryKey: ["account"] });
  console.log('Query invalidated and refetched');
  setTransactionSuccess(true);
},

Don't also forget that Supabase provides realtime features, Make sure there is no conflict between Supabase's realtime updates and React Query's caching mechanism.
You can set up a real-time subscription to listen for updates or changes:
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = supabase
    .from('accounts')
    .on('*', payload => {
      console.log('Change received!', payload);
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(['account']);
    })
   .subscribe();

  return () => {
    supabase.removeSubscription(subscription);
  };
}, [queryClient]);


Still didn't work i have been trying it.... Same result... I even checked supabase documentation for the subscription
